# escape quotes and single quote together in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes

I have problem with escaping quotes and single quote together.
I have a random string like this: Rome street "Cassia" 18
I use encodeUri to escape quotes

```
encodeUri('Rome street "Cassia" 18');
```

But i can also have a string like this: Rome stret 'Cassia' 18
I can't use same function becouse quote conflicting..

Help me!

Comment: Put the argument into a variable. That way you don't have to decide about quoting when passing the argument.

Comment: not working becouse the string can be random..

ex. string = "rome street "cassia" 18"; not working
string = "rome street 'cassia' 18'; working

Comment: How are you getting these strings?

Comment: customers addresses

Comment: Ehh ... I'm not interested in the source of the data contents, rather, how are you getting the data to the script. From a DB on a server? From a form (input element or sth.)? They are hardcoded in a JS file? Some other way?

Comment: partial resolved -> var newString = /data/;

but now i have problems with addresses those contain "/"

Comment: resolved -> var String = encodeURIComponent(/[$RDY_ANAG_String$]/);
 String = String.replace("%2F%5B",""); //replace /[
 String = String.replace("%5D%2F",""); //replace ]/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data ='Rome street "Cassia" 18';

var escaped_data=data.replace(/["']/g, "");
$("#data").append(escaped_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <p id="data"></p>
  
  <html>
```

Comment: not working for me..
the string can be Rome street "Cassia" 18 or Rome street 'Cassia' 18

first string working, second not..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the String to be URI encoded you could try this:

```
encodeURI(myString.replace(/[']/g, '"'))
```

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput"),
    myOutput = document.getElementById("myOutput");

myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  myOutput.innerHTML = encodeURI(myInput.value.replace(/[']/g, '"'));
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<p id="myOutput"></p>
```

Should you want to remove them completely the answer [Yuvraj Mudaliar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635855/5821619) gave should help.

Answer (score 0):

resolved!!

```
var String = encodeURIComponent(/[TEXT]/);
String = String.replace("%2F%5B",""); //replace /[
String = String.replace("%5D%2F",""); //replace ]/
```